# Flask not storing data to database

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Database not storing flask data models. Even though the database gets created.
Using postrges, the tables get created in bash view but not in pgAdmin. I have a simple app that needs to store data. Would appreciate help.'
Code uses SQLAlchemy. DO i need to use different library. I am using psycopg2 and sessions but havent imported sessions.

```
#!flask/bin/python
    #!flask/bin/python
          from os import linesep 
        from typing import Mapping, Type from flask
          import Flask,    jsonify 
    from flask import request 
      from slotscal import results 
     from flask_sqlalchemy 
     import SQLAlchemy
      import time 
      app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:test123@localhost:5432/hqw' app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False db=SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    
    
    db.metadata.clear()
        #add parenrts
    
    
    
    class Contracts(db.Model):
        name=db.Column(db.String(100))
        address=db.Column(db.String(42), unique=True, primary_key=True)
        fileName=db.Column(db.Integer)
        Functions= db.relationship('Function')
        Variables= db.relationship('Variable')
        StateVariables=db.relationship('StateVariable')
    
        def __init__(self,address,fileName,id,StateVariables,name):
            self.address=address
            self.fileName=fileName
            self.id=id
            self.StateVariables=StateVariables
            self.name=name
    
        
         class Function(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.String(42), db.ForeignKey('contracts.address'), primary_key=True)
        name=db.Column(db.String)
        lines=db.Column(db.Integer)
        ReachingTime=db.Column(db.DateTime)
        TrackingTime=db.Column(db.DateTime)
        Arguments= db.relationship('Arguments')
    
        def __init__(self,address,ReachingTime,id,TrackingTime,name,lines):
            self.address=address
            self.ReachingTime=ReachingTime
            self.TrackingTime=TrackingTime
            self.id=id
            self.lines=lines
            self.name=name
    
    class Argument(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.String(42), db.ForeignKey('function.id'), primary_key=True)
        Type=db.Column(db.String)
        Value=db.Column(db.String)
        Name=db.Column(db.String)
    
        def __init__(self,Name, id,Type,Value):
            self.Name=Name
            self.id=id
            self.Type=Type
            self.Value=Value
    
    class Variable(db.Model):
        
        VariableName=db.Column(db.String)
        id=db.Column(db.String(42),db.ForeignKey('contracts.address'),primary_key=True)
        Type=db.Column(db.String) 
        Value=db.Column(db.String)
        StateVaruiable=db.Column(db.Boolean)
        Mapping=db.Column(db.Boolean)
    
        def __init__(self,address,Value,Type,id,StateVariables,name):
            self.address=address
            self.Type=Type
            self.Value=Value
            self.id=id
            self.StateVariables=StateVariables
            self.name=name
        
    
    
    class m(db.Model): 
        id=db.Column(db.String(42),db.ForeignKey('variable.id'), primary_key=True)
        Type=db.Column(db.String)
        Source=db.Column(db.String)
    
        def __init__(self,Type,Source,id):
            self.Type=Type
            self.id=id
            self.Source=Source
    
    class StateVariable(db.Model):
        id=StateVariableType=db.Column(db.String)
        StateVariableValue=db.Column(db.String)
        id=db.Column(db.String(42),db.ForeignKey('contracts.address'),primary_key=True)
    
        
        def __init__(self,id,StateVariableType,StateVariableValue):
            self.StateVariableType=StateVariableType
            self.StateVariableValue=StateVariableValue
            self.id=id
           class Key(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.String(42),db.ForeignKey('m.id'), primary_key=True)
        Value=db.Column(db.String)
        Type=db.Column(db.String)
            
        def __init__(self,Value,id,Type):
            self.id=id
            self.Value=Value
            self.Type=Type
    
    
    
    class Analysis(db.Model): 
        id=db.Column(db.String(42),db.ForeignKey('contracts.address'),primary_key=True)
        FullTime=db.Column(db.DateTime)
        StateVariables=db.Column(db.Integer)
        
        def __init__(self,id,FullTime):
            self.id=id
            self.FullTime=FullTime
    
    
    @app.route('/') def index():
        return "Hello, World!" @app.route('/process', methods=['POST']) def process():
        #print ('h')
        header=request.json
        
        #print ('g')
        
        code=header['code']
        f=open('code.sol','w')
        f.write(code)
        f.close()
        path='./code.sol'   #filename
        subcon=header['name']   #name
        add=header['address']   #address
        contract=Contracts(subcon,add,path)
        db.session.add(contract)
        db.session.commit()
        lst=results(path,subcon,add)
        return jsonify({'task': lst})
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)**
```

Comment: What does "the tables get created in bash view" mean?  If you set `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` in the config does it show `CREATE TABLE` statements being emitted?  Are there errors when you run the app?  Are you sure pgadmin is looking at the right database?

Comment: The tables are created, I can see them but the data is not being stored

Comment: Then add some print statements to your route to see the values of the variables that you are passing to the `Contracts` object.  Again, setting  `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` should show you the SQL statements that are being sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you use the `db.metadata.clear()` for in your context.

Most likely, you don't see data in your DB, because there's nothing in your code to create the database relations. Standard solutions would include Alembic (Flask-Migrate package) or adding

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

to your code.
The particulars are really up to you. Flask-Migrate is quite easy:

1. Install: `pip install flask-migrate`
2. Add to model:

```
from flask-migrate import Migrate
...
app = Flask(...)
...
#db init code
...
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

3. Run:

initialize: `flask db init`

migrate: `flask db migrate -m "[YOUR MESSAGE]"`

upgrade: `flask db upgrade`

Here's a good source in addition to the official docs: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

Comment: It was meant to remove previous tables.

Comment: I get a alembic table but contracts save nothing. I have used from server import db and db.create_all(). Is this right?

Comment: I can't tell you what is or isn't working in your code that I can't see. You should use either Flask-Migrate or `db.create_all()`. If you use the latter, make sure you apply `with app.app_context():`
If you are using Flask-Migrate, you should see a new 'migrations' folder in your project directory after `flask db init`. I hope you comment out the `metadata.clear` command when you run your app.

Comment: I had already been using db.create_all(). I'll try again.